# what is the area of the polygon with given constraints?

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, area

What is the area of the polygon formed by all points $(x, y)$ in the plane satisfying the inequality  $ ||x| – 2 | + | |y| – 2 | ≤ 4 $ ?

Comment: what was the reason for thumbs down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your question says $$||x|-2|+||y|-2|\le4$$
Wolfram Alpha yields following plot
And according to that Area is $96$ sq units
[image]

Comment: I actually assumed the double absolute bars were a typo and the inequality should really read $$|x-2|+|y-2|\le 4$$ I guess that's why we should always use $LaTeX$ :)

Comment: no offence but isn't their a mathematical solution for the same .(i too could have used a computer for the same)

Comment: @houdini In what sense it's not mathematical?

Comment: @pew You meant $$\LaTeX$$ Right?

Comment: @DigitalBrain: Thanks, I was wondering how to do that, in most $\TeX$ editors it happens automatically.

Comment: @pew You're always welcome